# (Locust_Jmeter) TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

```py
response = self.client.get('/public/v1/users/', res_Id)
```

```
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: You need to post the _full_ stacktrace and not just the error itself, so we can have an idea as to the context of the error. You're clearly only passing 2 args in the code you've shown so there's just no way to help, that I can see, unless you give us more info.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I came into same issue and found.

You forgot to add 'self' object reference in your get() fun.

check your get()

Replace

```
def get(route , res_Id)
```

to

```
def get(self, route , res_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is res_Id?

Just remove `, res_Id`